# How to unique and sum the values based on the property key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have array of object data from my database, here is my data:

```
const data = [
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 0,
    'duration': '0 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 0,
    'duration': '0 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 1
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 2,
    'duration': '2 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 3,
    'duration': '3 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 5
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 5,
    'duration': '5 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 18,
    'duration': '18 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 6
  }
];
```

How can i unique them?(unique based on partnerId key) and then sum based on timeInt & totalProject key?

Expected result:

```
const data = [
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 21,
    'duration': '21 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 13
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 7,
    'duration': '7 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 5
  }
];
```

I already tried this:

```
let a = data.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(acc.find(y => y.partnerId === x.partnerId) ? [] : [x]), []);
```

But it's just for unique, not for sum the timeInt and totalProject key.

Any solution? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your approach: You just need to "alter" `x` before inserting it in your array, summing up your required properties (time / project) using `reduce`:

```js
const data = [{
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 0,
    'duration': '0 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 0,
    'duration': '0 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 1
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 2,
    'duration': '2 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 3,
    'duration': '3 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 5
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 2,
    'partnerName': 'Company2',
    'timeInt': 5,
    'duration': '5 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 2
  },
  {
    'partnerId': 1,
    'partnerName': 'Company1',
    'timeInt': 18,
    'duration': '18 days',
    'statusRanking': 'equal',
    'totalProject': 6
  }
]

let a = data.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if(acc.find(y => y.partnerId === x.partnerId)) return acc.concat([]);
  const timeInt = data.filter(y => y.partnerId === x.partnerId).map(y => y.timeInt).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  const totalProject = data.filter(y => y.partnerId === x.partnerId).map(y => y.totalProject).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return acc.concat([{
    ...x,
    timeInt,
    totalProject,
    duration: timeInt + ' days'
  }])}, []);

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `loadsh`'s `groupBy` and `sumBy` to make the task easy. something like this

```
const {groupBy, sumBy} = require("lodash");
const data = [
  {
    "partnerId": 1,
    "partnerName": "Company1",
    "timeInt": 0,
    "duration": "0 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 2
  },
  {
    "partnerId": 2,
    "partnerName": "Company2",
    "timeInt": 0,
    "duration": "0 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 1
  },
  {
    "partnerId": 2,
    "partnerName": "Company2",
    "timeInt": 2,
    "duration": "2 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 2
  },
  {
    "partnerId": 1,
    "partnerName": "Company1",
    "timeInt": 3,
    "duration": "3 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 5
  },
  {
    "partnerId": 2,
    "partnerName": "Company2",
    "timeInt": 5,
    "duration": "5 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 2
  },
  {
    "partnerId": 1,
    "partnerName": "Company1",
    "timeInt": 18,
    "duration": "18 days",
    "statusRanking": "equal",
    "totalProject": 6
  }
];


const unique = groupBy(data, i => i.partnerId);

const result = Object.keys(unique).map(key => {
  const first = unique[key][0];
  return {
    ...first,
    "timeInt": sumBy(unique[key], i => i.timeInt),
    "totalProject": sumBy(unique[key], i => i.totalProject)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow! this is also an easy way! thank you @Ashish Modi

Comment: @masdap glad it helped. I always believe in if a library is available to mkae life easy and code clean, we should use. feel free it to mark it as answer for other people's reference.